# User name for HackageDB?

Tags: haskell, hackage

I want to upload a package to HackageDB, and since I'm new to this I need user name and password. It says [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/accounts.html) I'm supposed to write to Ross Paterson. I've been trying for some weeks, but got no response. Is this just taking some time, or has the process maybe changed?

Comment: send him a present, maybe some chocolats, or cigars.

Comment: by e-mail? virtual ones :-)?

Comment: hm, then you should find new ways. maybe something like this will do it: http://static.someecards.com/someecards/usercards/c5e43a9c568b53298c4b9a674c231c3244.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be persistent, but I think you can speed the process if you can show him that you are a trusted and active member of the community.  I believe he does some basic background checks when he gets time and if you have a blog or Github account that he can briefly check then I think it will make things go quicker.

However, it's not totally necessary.  For example, I didn't have any online presence when I first asked for an account and he still eventually approved me anyway.  Just keep at it and he will respond.

Comment: Thanks,Gabriel! I just sent him a link to my patch-tag repository, see if this helps :-)!